# How to configure a WLAN connection for an SSID that is not enabled right now

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I'm struggeling with an attempt to configure a WLAN connection in an Ubuntu system (20.04), where the access point is not yet visible.

I try to prepare a laptop for use with a WLAN, but I have no access to that WLAN while setting it up.

What I tried is to set it up by "Connect to Hidden Network...". There I could enter all the details to my WLAN.  It seems that it creates a connnection (I can see it in the UI and with command line "nmcli c s MY_SSID"). After a few seconds it shows a popup "Connection failed - Activateion of network connection failed". This makes sense at the network is not yet visible. Anyhow the connection aperas then in the list of the UI with "Known Wi-Fi Networks". But when the laptop later gets in range of the WLAN it doesn't connect it automatically.

Question: Is it possible to setup a WLAN connection that will be connected when in range? Are there any special parameters option (maybe with the "nmcli" tool) to allow to set up this connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question in an old post. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165133/networkmanager-will-not-autoconnect-to-wireless-if-it-is-unavailable-at-creation)

Actually it is the intended behavior in the NetworkManager 1.22.10. As a user wrote in the linked post the behavior was reverted in later versions.